# Covering balls by balls of half radius in compact metric space (or, comparing Haar measure between balls of comparable radius)

Tags: metric-spaces, compactness, locally-compact-groups, haar-measure

Let $(X,d)$ be a compact metric space. Given $r>0$ I can obviously cover any ball $B(x,r)$ by finitely many balls $B(x_j,r/2)$, $j=1,...,k(r)$, by compactness. My question is whether there is always a finite number $k$, which doesn't depend on the radius $r$ and is such that any $r$-ball in $(X,d)$ can be covered by $k$-many $r/2$-balls?

Actually, what I would like to know is the following and I thought the previous question might be something simpler which also happens to answer my question; Let $X$ be a compact abelian group with Haar measure $m$. Is there a constant $c>0$, such that for any $r>0$ we have $m(B(x,r)) \leq c \cdot m(B(x,r/2))$? (again, the point is that $c$ wouldn't depend on the radius $r$)

Comment: In $R^n$ a ball has measure  of order $r^n$ so comparing volumes at least $2^n$ balls are needed to cover the larger one. Maybe one can take a product of such spaces (with growing number of half-balls needed) to see that, in general there is no such $k$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a compact metric space the general answer is no.

In fact, your condition has a name.  A metric space $X$ such that every ball of radius $r$ can be covered by $k$-many balls of radius $\frac{r}{2}$ is called [**doubling.**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubling_space)  It turns out the doubling condition is equivalent to having finite [Assouad dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assouad_dimension), which is stronger than having finite Hausdorff dimension, which in turn is stronger than having finite topological dimension.

Also any space with a doubling measure  $(\mu(2B)\leq C\mu(B)$ for some constant $C$, for every ball $B$) must have a doubling metric, which is an easy exercise.

Therefore any metrizable compact abelian group with infinite topological dimension will do as a counter-example.  For example, the countably infinite product of the circle with itself $\left(\mathbb R/\mathbb Z\right)^{\mathbb N}$ cannot have a doubling metric, thus its Haar measure cannot be doubling with respect to an invariant metric (or any compatible metric, for that matter).

Comment: That was very much unexpected; thanks.